# How do I insert a front/cover page in my latex document?

Tags: packages, miktex

I want to use a front/cover page from my university in my paper, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. The website which you can download it from tells me that I have to download `ku-cover.zip` and extract it in `TEXMF\tex\latex` and afterwards update the package overview.

I use MiKTeX + Texstudios but I just cannot figure out how to make it work. I can't find that folder anywhere?

Here's the website in case you wanna try for yourself: [Website with cover-page](http://www.math.ku.dk/~m00cha/)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might want to read the existing posts about installing a custom package. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/124577

Comment: Well, actually, you don't need to download anything to add a custom cover page made by you to your thesis. However, it seems that your university already has a format that you should download and put into the appropriate directory within your LaTeX installation. In Windows you have to go to the `control panel` and inside `C:` you must find in `Files and programs`, the appropriate directory where to place it. 

Read the answer to which you have been redirected and you will have it clearer.

Comment: TEXMF is a variable and not the actual name of a folder. The variable contains the path to the appropriate folder (at least on Linux, I never installed LaTeX on a Windows machine). If it's not a variable it still is a placeholder for a path and not a folders name by itself.

Answer (score 2):

The content of file `ku-cover.zip` can simply copied into a new directory, for example `ku-cover`. Inside this directory you can then compile example file `eksempel.tex` with an resulting error: "Optional Clash for package color".

This error results in a wrong oder of calls of packages in file `ku-forside.sty`.

You need to change the original (`eso-pic` calls package `color`)

```
\RequirePackage{eso-pic,graphicx,fix-cm,ae,aecompl,ifthen}         %
\RequirePackage[usenames]{color} %
```

to

```
\RequirePackage[usenames]{color} %
\RequirePackage{eso-pic,graphicx,fix-cm,ae,aecompl,ifthen}
```

Please see that this `sty` files uses the outdated packages `ae` and `aecompl`.

If possible, please ask for an updated version ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you use MiKTeX under (I suppose) Windows, you should put all files which are not part of the distribution in a `local` root directory. If you don't have  one, first create  a directory, say `TeXMF-local\`,  and add this directory as a new root directory with `MiKTeX Settings(Admin)`, `roots` tab, like this:
[image]

(Note: `D:\` in this example is   there because I installed my scientific applications on an own partition of my h.d. This is of course not necessary.)

Next, copy the contents of `ku-cover.zip` in this directory, respecting the T.D.S. (TeX Directory Architecture).

Last, always with MiKTeX Settings, `General` tab, refresh the FNBD. The installed files can now be used.

Comment: When I try this I get the error:
ku-side.st - error - Optional Clash for package color.
Is it because I done something wrong?
@Bernard

Comment: It's probably due to loading `xcolor` twice , with different options. It's easy to solve, but we need to have a full, yet minimal (non-)working example, and where to get `ku-cover`.

Comment: the link for the zip file is in the post.

Comment: And  a minimal example? We need to know you preamble, as there might be conflicts.

Comment: What do you mean by example? A picture of what I get or? Sorry I'm confused

Comment: Any complete code reproducing the problem. I guess you must be loading `xcolor` with an option, or you load some package(s) which load(s)  it with option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71264/discussion-between-seht111-and-bernard).